# How do I get the shop page back to original?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Last year I altered the shop page to only display categories. I switched themes and would like to redo the shop page. No matter what I do it reverts to the old format. I tried uninstall and reinstall of Woocommerce and it stayed. Tried leaving it but just setting the shop page to a different page in Woo Commerce settings and it stayed. I want to create a new page to replace this one but it just reverts to this page- http://germanhausbarn.com/shop/ If you look at the bottom of this page you will see products below the newsletter area. Why can't I edit this page? Or how can I get it back to how it is after fresh install?

Comment: Without knowing *how* you altered the code, how would we help? If you created a template override, you'll need to remove it.

Comment: That is what I am trying to figure out is how to remove a template override. The other answer would be how to just install a non modified version of Woocommerce.

Comment: To remove an override, simply remove the override files. The CMS app looks for those first. If they aren't there, the original files are used. This article may give some insight into where those files reside. https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-override-woocommerce-template-files/